# No default driver specified

Tags: vb.net, windows, oracle

I am trying to connect to Oracle 9i database using below VB code:

```
strConnection = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=SERVERNAME;Uid=USERID;Pwd=PASSWORD"        
Connect = New ADODB.Connection 
Connect.Open(strConnection)
```

The last line throws me below error:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data Source Name not found and no
>   default driver specified

The VB code is working fine and able to connect to dev database in dev server. The same script is not working in UAT server. The TNS entries are fine. Both the servers are of Windows server 2008 - 32 bit.

When I checked the drivers tab in ODBC Data Source Administrator, dev server has below entry:

> Microsoft ODBC For Oracle - 6.00.6001.18000 - Microsoft Corporation -
>   MSORCL32.dll - Date

Whereas UAT server has below entry:
**Microsoft ODBC For Oracle -**

The driver **Microsoft ODBC for oracle** is listed in the drivers tab of UAT server but does not have the version & dll file details. Is this driver not installed properly? If yes, how to re install it? Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: The problem is clearly mentioned in the error message. The data source property is missing in your connectionString.

Comment: Why do you use outdated ADO (i.e. `ADODB`) connection in an VB.NET application?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your responses.

My Tech lead corrected the issue by installing the ODBC driver and by making some changes to the registry.

@Wernfried Domscheit - We are trying to use the existing VB script due to time constraint. Even though it is old, we are not intended to make any changes to it.

Regards,
Tamil